# MapKit: rendering MKCircle with unwelcome artifacts

Tags: swift, xcode, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkcircle

I'm using MKCircle for displaying the user location on MKMapView. This is done by a few lines of code:

`MKCircle` creation:

```
self.mapCircle = MKCircle(center: pinLocation, radius: 50)
self.mapView.add(self.mapCircle!)
```

Rendering, using `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        guard let circle = overlay as? MKCircle else { return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay) }

        let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: circle)

        renderer.strokeColor = .red
        renderer.lineWidth = 1

        return renderer
}
```

It is behaving pretty well untill I zoom out and zoom in back. Then i get the vertical line artefact, which is appearing at the same place all time. It doesn't depend on the stroke width.

[image: my annoying stroke artefact]

Does anyone know any solution to avoid appearing that artefact?

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? There's a few questions around MKMapView overlays with artefacts but none seem to have an answer.

Comment: Hi @KaneCheshire. I changed the design, so I didn't need to deal with this bug anymore. I would appreciate if you inform me once you find a solution.

Comment: I haven't yet, but I'm playing around with overriding drawMapRect to make sure it only draws into the map which intersects with the circle. Seems promising.

Comment: @DmitriyKirakosyan did you manage to solve anything related to this?
I'm struggling to find any kind of useful solution (in my case just polylines in general)

Comment: @Programmer, I didn't unfortunately and I'm not on this project anymore. TBH I'm surprised this bug still exists...